# Empty Twitter Bootstrap icons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<a>
   <i class="icon-trash"></i>
</a>
```

This is actually what i use as buttons on my site. But some times i get totally empty buttons without any images (backgrounds) in my . i'm confused. How to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked that the icon actually exists? (icon name)

Answer (score 0):

you need to refresh the browser, or clear it's cache.